# what is the solution to design multiple pages website that all pages has the same form but different in 2 fields each

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net web form application which is an employee request system 
     ,all pages share the same info but  differs in 2 or 3 fields depending on 
     an employee position , what is the best way to make single page front and 
     back- end , i don't know if i have to repeat the same page for 10 types of 
     employees? i am thinking to process the problem using java script to show 
     or hide front end depending on employee type and do the same on back-end

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if (hiddenFiledEmpType.val()='1')
 {
  $('belongstoemplyeetype4').hide;
  $('belongstoemplyeetype3').show;
 }

 </script>
 <div id="belongstoemplyeetype1" display="none"></div>
 <div id="belongstoemplyeetype2" display="none"></div>
 <div id="belongstoemplyeetype3" display="none"></div>
 <div id="belongstoemplyeetype4" display="none"></div>
 <asp:HiddenField runtat="server" id="hiddenFieldEmpType"/>


 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
 <%
 hiddenFieldEmptype.val=1;            
 %>
```

Comment: no don't repeat the same page. Instead use C# to detect the employee type and then vary what is displayed. I wouldn't do it on the front-end because people can meddle with that and get access to fields they shouldn't. Much easier to implement it on the back-end and validate the input there as well. Anything you do in JS is just for improved UX, not for actual security.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson , do you mean that i have to show and hide divs in the backend and make divs runat="server"?

Comment: yes. You could use `<asp:Panel` controls of course, which are a bit easier to handle in the backend, but they get rendered as divs on the front end